# Validate Multiple Dropdown in .NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, .net-6.0

Im trying to validate a dropdown list where you can select multiple entries. If you don't select any element it should show me an error message, when i try to submit the form. Why doesn't it work?

## View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model =>
    model.ChosenEmployeesIds,
    Model.Employees,
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"class", string.Format("form-control chosen-select {0}", Model.IsUserAlleMA ? "defaultSelect": "")},
        {"id", "EmployeesList"},
        {"multiple", ""}
    })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChosenEmployeesIds, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

## Viewmodel

```
[Required, MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Choose at least 1 Element.")]
public IEnumerable<int> ChosenEmployeesIds { get; set; }
```

## Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public FileResult Download(DownloadsViewModel viewModel)
{
    var zipMemoryStream = DoSomething();
    return File(zipMemoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", zipName);
}
```

Comment: can you post the controller action this is posted to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the model state is valid in the controller action as well. If it isn't, return the view which should now show your validation message.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public FileResult DownloadByEmployee(DownloadsViewModel viewModel)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //return View(viewModel);
        return View("Index", viewModel);
    }

    // Prepare zip name
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    var zipName = $"name{currentDate}.zip";

    // Zip archive can write into a stream, memory stream is used to keep
    // data only on the short-term memory (RAM)
    using (var zipMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipMemoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
        {
            foreach (var employeeId in viewModel.ChosenEmployeesIds)
            {
                var userCertificates = _userCertificateRepository
                            .Get(uc => uc.EmployeeId == employeeId)
                            .ToList();
                        
                WriteUserCertificateFilesIntoZipArchive(zipArchive, userCertificates, true);
            }
        }

        return File(zipMemoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", zipName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to use `return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index"));` but i still dont see a validation message

Comment: @Ronnie if you redirect then youre losing the posted viewmodel which contains information about the modelstate which is likely why youre seeing a fresh page load instead of the error message. Based on your comment above, It looks like your corresponding `GET` action that loads the view is called `Index`. So use `return View("Index", viewModel)` inside the `if(!ModelState.IsValid)` block instead. This way youre passing the `viewModel` which contains the appropriate `ModelState` data back to the view. I've updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still have to use `return RedirectToAction("Index", viewModel);`, because otherwise i get redirected to the wrong page. But there's still no error message.

Comment: you have complete control over what view you respond with from the server (without a full redirect). I'm having trouble making sense of that. Is the `GET` action called `Index` and in the same controller as your `DownloadByEmployee` `POST` action? If so, then `return View("Index", viewModel)` should work

Comment: Its a POST Method that should return a File, what works fine. If i use `return View("Index", viewModel)` the browser opens a site of the Controller name, that doesn't exist.

Comment: please post the method signature of the `GET` action youre trying to return the user to, the name of the controller it's in and the name of the controller your `DownloadByEmployee` action is in

Comment: DownloadByEmployee Controller: DownloadsController
GET Action: `public ActionResult Index()`

Both methods are in the same controller

Comment: One more request: please post the `RegisterRoutes` method of your `RouteConfig.cs`

Comment: I dont have a RouteConfig.cs

Comment: But thats the pattern: `"{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"`

Answer (score 0):

For client validation,you need to check if you have refered

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js" ></script>
```

notice not reserve the order

and set a value to errormessage in @Html.ValidationMessageFor()

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChosenEmployeesIds, "errormessage", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

And it may help if you could share more details of your model and you could press F12 to observe the codes which has been complied to html and share it with us